# Typing a class component with no props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-class-based-component

I am trying to type a class component with no props

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

type Props = {};

class MyComponent extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>hello</h1>;
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

It seems like I just cannot ommit them

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }
```

What is the correct way to type a class component with no props?

Comment: You can mostly omit them: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkifAL5wBmURcARFKhowNwBQnaANigGcBcALIBPQsTIU4SAB4xyAE2GTI0+Dk5w4aUgJhQArhmgAKMPTACAXLkoBKXNp1wBRsEigWrAh11c4GAALYAEAOgMURTgAXlw4YMEAUSh6KDsaFF4BJDhKAPzuHRYSJS8zJy1AlhgjKBI4AB5ggEYAPmCkXl4IJoB6NvbCyk5KIA

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the state like this, avoiding to (manually) overwrite the constructor.

```
class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  state = {
    hasError: false
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>hello</h1>;
  }
}
```

I think that's what you're talking about, not the typings.